# multiple dropdowns using the same jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this other issue where  I have multiple dropdowns which have the same jquery function. When  I select the 1st  project dropdown the the corresponding  task dropdown gets selected. But when i have multiple dropdown only the first task drop down gets selected.  when there are multiple dropdowns when the project is selected in the dropdown i want the corresponding task dropdown to be updated.

My Task dropdown look like this

```
 <select id="task_id" name="tasks_id[]" size="8" multiple="1">
    <optgroup label="01 CONSULT" >
      <option value="1">1a Rules</option>
      <option value="2">1b Vacation</option>
      <option value="3" >1c Meetings</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="02 SALES" >
      <option value="12"> 2c Internal</option>
      <option value="13"> 2d External </option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Html code**

```
 <%= select_tag "task_id[]", options_from_collection_for_select([unspecified_task], 'id', 'name', entry.task_id || unspecified_task.id) + grouped_options_for_select(active_task_options, entry.task_id.to_s) %>
```

I want to know how to write the jquery so that when their are multiple dropdowns and a project is selected the corresponding task drop down will be populated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you have same id or name for multiple dropdowns.

Comment: yes i have the same id for multiple dropdowns and hence want to know how to resolve this issue

Comment: Each element in html should have unique id. Assign unique id to each multiple dropdowns. This should solve your problem.

Comment: what happens if you have like 10 elements? it will be too much. how would you suggest that we do it?